# Encoding externally saved bytes throws an error and prevents the project from building

Tags: c#, file, security, encoding, byte

Ok, this is kind of a weird thing that's happening that I just can't seem to find a solution for.

I've been working with Tweetinvi in C# for a couple of days now and I have been working on the authentication process. What I'm doing at the moment is I retrieve two access tokens for the user using PIN-based authentication. I then encrypt those and store three values in a zip file.

Here's the code for that:

```
            byte[] entropy = new byte[20];
            using (RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                rng.GetBytes(entropy);
            }

            byte[] accessBytes = ProtectedData.Protect(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Globals.userCredentials.AccessToken), entropy, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
            byte[] accessSecretBytes = ProtectedData.Protect(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Globals.userCredentials.AccessTokenSecret), entropy, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);

            // Create temporary directory to store encrypted data

            if (!Directory.Exists(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\_temp_zip"))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\_temp_zip");
            }

            // Write files
            File.WriteAllBytes(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\_temp_zip\\ent.txt", entropy);
            File.WriteAllBytes(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\_temp_zip\\acc1.txt", accessBytes);
            File.WriteAllBytes(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\_temp_zip\\acc2.txt", accessSecretBytes);

            // Check if zip already exists. If true, delete
            if(File.Exists(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\cred.zip"))
            {
                File.Delete(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\cred.zip");
            }

            // Add files to zip
            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\_temp_zip", "cred.zip");

            // Delete temp directory
            Directory.Delete(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\_temp_zip", true);
```

On start up, the program checks to see if the zip file exists. If it does, it opens up the zip and extracts the files to a temp directory. The bytes of each file are read in, and the access tokens are unprotected and ecoded back to strings.

```
            if (!Directory.Exists(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\_temp_zip"))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\_temp_zip");
            }

            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\cred.zip", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\_temp_zip");

            byte[] entropy = File.ReadAllBytes(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\_temp_zip" + "\\ent.txt");
            byte[] accessBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\_temp_zip" + "\\acc1.txt");
            byte[] accessSecretBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\_temp_zip"+ "\\acc2.txt");

            // Delete temp directory
            Directory.Delete(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\_temp_zip", true);

            // Translate bytes to text
            byte[] cipherAccessToken = ProtectedData.Unprotect(accessBytes, entropy, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
            byte[] cipherAccessTokenSecret = ProtectedData.Unprotect(accessSecretBytes, entropy, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);

            string accessToken = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(accessBytes);
            string accessTokenSecret = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(accessSecretBytes);
```

Everything works all fine and dandy, until the program gets to the last two lines. For some reason, if those lines are left in, Visual Studio will simply refuse to build the solution. At first I thought it was a problem with Costura.Fody, but I removed that from the project and the problem persisted.

I checked and double checked that the bytes I read in are the same bytes that I wrote in the first place, and they definitely appear to be correct. It simply refuses to encode the bytes back to a string and I can't figure out why. Is there perhaps a different way I can encode and then decode the bytes so that it will build, or is there a different problem underlying all of this?

Comment: Try to 'Clean' then 'Rebuild' your solution. If there is no syntax error then it should be able to build correctly since `Encoding.UTF8.GetString` is used correctly for your case. Can you share the exact error thrown?

Comment: @Ephraim Cleaning then Rebuilding does not seem to help, I get the same error as before. The error claims it does not have access to the path where the exe file is built. "Access to the path 'E:\SVA\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitter Timeline\Twitter Timeline\obj\Debug\Twitter Timeline.exe' is denied."

Comment: In my experience with access denied error on build, there is a process that failed to terminate using Twitter Timeline.exe... You can verify this by opening TaskManager. You'll see a running process corresponding to the application involved. Right click and end task this process then clean-rebuild.

Comment: Can't seem to find anything involving the application... and again, it builds fine with those two lines commented out, but doesn't otherwise.

Comment: Hmmm a weird issue. Have you tried restarting the computer? Since if you failed to identify the process using the Twitter Timeline.exe, it should be gone after a reboot. Don't remove the two lines. Go straight for a build. Because seriously, if it is not a syntax error then it should build fine.

Comment: Just restarted, still failed to build. [Here](http://pastebin.com/gRHmbZ6m) is the Output VS spits out if it helps any.